# 'TypeError: jQuery is undefined' after Partial Update - OctoberCMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, octobercms

I have an OctoberCMS component that has an AJAX Handler for `onSelectTag`, but when the `#posts` HTML element is updated (rendered) with the `blogPosts/postList` partial, the following error is thrown:

> TypeError: jQuery is undefined

#### tagList.htm:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
<button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-request="onSelectTag" data-request-data="tagId: {{ tag.id }}">{{ tag.name }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

#### onSelectTag() AJAX Handler:

```
public function onSelectTag()
{
    $this->page['posts'] = Post::all();

    // below is where the partial updates / renders
    return [
        '#posts' => $this->renderPartial('blogPosts/postList.htm')
    ];
}
```

#### blogPosts/postList.htm:

```
[viewBag]
==
{% if posts is empty %}
{% set posts = __SELF__.posts %}
{% endif %}
{% if not hideFeatured is defined %}
  {% set hideFeatured = __SELF__.property('hideFeatured') %}
{% endif %}
{% set pageSlug = post.slug %}
{% if not hideFeatured %}
<div class="row" id="highlight">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="card" id="featured">
      <a href="{{ posts.first.url }}">
        {% if posts.first.featured_images.count %}
          <img src="{{ posts.first.featured_images[0].path }}" alt="{{ posts.first.title }}" class="card-img-top">
        {% endif %}
        {% if posts.first.categories.count %}
            <p class="card-header">
            {% for category in posts.first.categories %}
                <a href="{{ category.url }}" class="badge badge-secondary">{{ category.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
            </p>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-body bg-success text-white">
            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{{ posts.first.url }}" class="text-white">{{ posts.first.title | upper }}</a> <small class="float-right">{{ posts.first.published_at|date('F d, Y') }}</small></h5>
            <hr class="tagline"/>
            <p class="card-text">{{ posts.first.summary|striptags|length > 150 ? posts.first.summary|striptags|slice(0, 150) ~ '...' : posts.first.summary|striptags}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          <span><i class="fas fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tags: </span>
          {% if posts.first.tags.count %}
              {% for tag in posts.first.tags %}
                  <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ tag.name }}</span>
              {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
              <span class="badge badge-danger">No Tags</span>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            {% partial 'youtube' %}
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="card">
            <h4 class="card-header">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h4>
            <div class="card-body">
                {% partial 'mail-chimp' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
<br />
<div class="card-columns">
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if loop.first and not hideFeatured %}
    <!-- First Post is Featured -->
    {% elseif post.slug != pageSlug %}
    <a href="{{ url('/blog/post/' ~ post.slug) }}">
        <div class="card">
            {% if post.featured_images.count %}
            <img src="{{ post.featured_images[0].path }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ post.title }}">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title text-center"><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title | upper }}</a></h4>
                <p class="card-subtitle text-muted text-center">{{ post.published_at|date('F d, Y') }}</p>
                {% if post.categories.count %}
                    {% for category in post.categories %}
                    <a href="{{ url('/blog/category/' ~ category.slug) }}" class="badge badge-success">{{ category.name }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                <hr class="tagline" />
                <div class="card-text">{{ post.summary|striptags|length > 50 ? post.summary|striptags|slice(0, 50) ~ '...' : post.summary|striptags}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                <span><i class="fas fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tags: </span>
                {% if post.tags.count %}
                    {% for tag in post.tags %}
                    <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ tag.name }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                <span class="badge badge-danger">No Tags</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
<h3 class="no-data">{{ noPostsMessage }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="row">
{% if posts.lastPage > 1 %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if posts.currentPage > 1 %}
            <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage-1) }) }}">&larr; Prev</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for page in 1..posts.lastPage %}
            <li class="{{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if posts.lastPage > posts.currentPage %}
            <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage+1) }) }}">Next &rarr;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="subscribeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="subscribeModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-md-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="subscribeModalTitle">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {% partial 'mail-chimp' %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion subscribe-footer" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER <i class="fas fa-chevron-up subscribe-chevron" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            {% partial 'mail-chimp' %}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion subscribe-footer-mobile" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    SUBSCRIBE <i class="fas fa-chevron-up subscribe-chevron" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            {% partial 'mail-chimp' %}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think the reference or load order is the issue because I've tried moving the jQuery reference and the `{% framework extras %}` reference and the `{% scripts %}` reference to many different parts of the page, and nothing changed either way.

#### My theory:

I think that when the partial updates, it's messing up the jQuery Framework call or something. It's odd because jQuery functions still work like:

```
$('#tagFilter').on('input', function() {
    console.log("TEST");
});
```

That still works, but functions defined by the OctoberCMS AJAX framework like `$.request(...)` do not work. I'm not sure why this is happening though.

Comment: Make sure you load `JQuery` in before your inline script.  where did you pull the `$.request` method from? did you declare it manually? I'm not seeing it as a JQuery method.

Comment: @zfrisch I appreciate the response. `$.request` is a part of the OctoberCMS / Laravel AJAX framework. The script is in 'blog.js' which is loaded after jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question again and noticed that you seem to be including the jquery library but don't show the layout code.

I have also ran into this problem. Multi-depth ajax doesn't work and breaks the content from using the whole dom. It might have something to do with the life cycles of partials.

---

Leaving this for anyone who was a fool like me in the beginning.

`{{ framework extras }}` doesn't actually load the jquery library. Here is the default template code for Octobercms. [Referenced here in the docs.](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction#framework-script)

```
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ 'assets/vendor/jquery.js'|theme }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ 'assets/vendor/bootstrap.js'|theme }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ 'assets/javascript/app.js'|theme }}"></script>
        {% framework extras %}
        {% scripts %}
```

I am calling `<script src="{{ 'assets/vendor/jquery.js'|theme }}"></script>` in the head of my layout which connects to a minimized and compressed version of some jquery.

Also the `{% scripts %}` is how you want to handle inserted scripts. [Referenced here in the docs.](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-scripts)